# How can I make use of LOCAL VARIABLES within a heroku postgres query?

Tags: database, node.js, postgresql, heroku, postgresql-9.3

I have looked around in many MANY threads, and through various documentation however for what seems like such an incredibly SIMPLE task, this is driving me insane.

I have a node.js webapp which generates a userId upon login, and is stored within a session object.

req.user.id <== my local variable for the user id.

A snippet of the code I have so far is along these lines:

```
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM programs WHERE authorid = req.user.id", function (err, result) {

    if (err){
      //Do erranous things
    } else { 
      // Do good things
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I do this simple task of comparing a database entry to a value stored in a local variable?

Any / all help appreciated - I've been trying to do this for 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [github page](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) for the Node.js PostgreSQL client, it looks like you can pass and use arguments like:

```
client.query("SELECT * FROM programs WHERE authorid = $1", 
  [req.user.id], function(err, result) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'd tried similar things but it seems I was confusing the syntax. You're a life saver.